# PHP Generate Random String In Echo

Tags: php, random, phpseclib

I'm looking for a bit of assistance in generating a random string of numbers that is 4 digits long. To better explain my situation, here is a snippet of PHP code where I need the random numbers inserted (for those wondering about the `$ssh->exec` I'm using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)).

```
echo $ssh->exec("touch $username-$port.txt");
```

The above `$port` variable is where I'd like PHP to generate a random 4 digit number (preferably between 5000-5999).

After looking at the [documentation on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_rand.asp), it looks like they recommend using the following to generate a random number between defined limits, like so:

```
echo(rand(10,100));
```

This works standalone, but the problem with that is it requires an `echo` and I'm already performing an `echo $ssh->exect` with my above PHP code. So I'm not quite sure how I would implement an "echo inside an echo" if that makes sense.

If anyone would be willing to help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$port = rand(5000,5999); echo $ssh->exec("touch $username-$port.txt");` that should work.

Comment: `echo $ssh->exec("touch $username-".rand(5,9).".txt");` is going to work as well

Comment: Actually `echo $ssh->exec("touch $username.$port.txt");` with a period to concatenate or with a seperator `echo $ssh->exec("touch $username."_".$port.txt");`

Comment: Bah, I feel like a noob. Thank you guys. @Fred-ii- your `$port = rand(5000,5999);` worked perfectly. Very much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Would you like my comment as an answer to close the question? @CRUNCH It's your choice.

Comment: If @Fred-ii- would like to, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: It has been done @CRUNCH *cheers* glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pre-defined variable such as:

```
$port = rand(5000,5999);
```

that will then populate through your `exec` provided you keep it encapsulated inside double quotes. Otherwise, you will need to concatenate.